# Не удается вывести значение нажатой кнопки из первой функции Telebot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def vacancy(message):
    markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.add('1', '2')
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Выберите число:", reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, gorod)

def gorod(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.add('один', 'второй')
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Выберите предмет:", reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, query)
       
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
def query(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Держи

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("ТОКЕН")

markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
markup.add('1', '2')
markup1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
markup1.add('один', 'второй')
    
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def vacancy(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Выберите число:", reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, gorod)

def gorod(message):
    num = message.text.lower()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, num)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Выберите предмет:", reply_markup=markup1)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, query)
       
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
def query(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
    
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```